# How do I seed a production database

Tags: google-app-maker

When you do a new deployment, it makes an empty copy of the database. I was thinking I could use the preview instance to seed my database. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes it is. You have to use the option **Use Custom Cloud SQL database** and put there the SQL cloud database key.

Comment: thanks (sorry for the late reply).